# Highlighted menu items are highlighting too early in a parallax effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to build a website with a parallax effect and dynamically highlighted menu items.

For the moment everything works fine (parallax and menu items) but combined the menu items get a strange behaviour. They are highlighted too early, so the menu items swap from 'home' to 'company' on beginning of the 'home' site and so on.

This is the JS code I am using

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.parallax').scroll(function() {

        var position = $(this).scrollTop();

        $('.parallax__group').each(function() {

            var target = $(this).offset().top;
            var id = $(this).attr('id');

            if (position >= target) {
                $('a').removeClass('active');
                $("a[href='#"+id+"']").addClass('active');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

As I said... it's well working but the menu items are not highlighted when it reaches a new group, but way earlier. What could be the source of the problem? I can provide more code if needed.

Comment: Post the css and html, I think it is in the css.

Comment: We won't be able to tell without seeing the HTML and the CSS involved here as well.

Comment: Oh my... One is getting blind if one is working long enough on the project ;-) The hint with the css was gold for me, I had a stupid size management for the background layers which confronted with my base layers... Thanks!